# Printing when there's only a single record in MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql

What's the best way to print from MySQL using PHP when you know there's only going to be a single record?

My SQL statement is:

```
select user from users where user = 'norman';
```

This will return only a single record. So what's the best way to print it? I currently do:

```
while ($info=mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
```

etc

But that's OK for more than one record. Any better way to do this when there's only one?

Comment: Check you have at least 1 value, and then fetch it and process.  If you check num_rows and its 1 you can do a fetch, if its >1 you can use the while loop.

Comment: To ensure that you always return a single result AND to speed the query up a bit add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're absolutely certain that this query will always retrieve 1 row then this should be enough:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
```

Then you can manipulate $row (the single row) at your will.

Answer (score 1):

`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));`

then do what you want:

`echo $row['value'];`

You need to know in advance that this is going to return a single row. You could use a function:

```
function fetch_single_row($sql){
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 1){
    return false;
  }
  return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

Comment: Using the function is negligibly slower than just doing `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));`, but makes your code cleaner, and more error resistant :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    include 'opendb.php';

    $query  = "select user from users where user = 'norman";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "Name :{$row['user']}";
    }

    include 'closedb.php';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just leave off the while. It will probably make execution a minute bit faster.